# main.py is running in an infinite loop on a esp8266 board

Tags: esp8266, micropython

I have a esp8266 board running micropython. From windows 10, I pushed a main.py file to the board using ampy. The script simply flashes the boards led lights. Unfortunately, it does so in an infinite loop.
Now, I am unable to stop the program which is preventing me from connecting to the board again to replace that test code with a real project.
I tried using ampy to send an interrupt via the command line, it failed to work.Sort of buying a new board and starting over is there anyway out of this corner I created?

Thanks
Bill

Comment: I finally found the answer. I used esptool with the argument erase_flash. That did the trick